# How to get error messag error messages in ajaxerror() method using selenium java

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, selenium

I want to get the error message that was developed in the ajax error() method. I have tried all wait mechanisms but, it only captures the status of the button: "Sending".

**Code snippet**

```
 List<WebElement> Shops=driver.findElements(By.className("card")) ;
     
    System.out.print("Size  " + Shops.size());
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    
    for(int i=0; i<Shops.size(); i++)
    { 
        try { // Handle Exceptions
            
     Shops.get(i).click(); //click on specific mailbox
     
     WebElement Conn_setting= driver.findElement(By.linkText("Connection Settings"));
     Conn_setting.click();     // click on connection Settings
     
     
    
     
     WebElement Send_Test=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"send-test-trigger\"]"));
    
     
    JavascriptExecutor j = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
     
     
     
     WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(100));
     wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(Send_Test));
     j.executeScript("arguments[0].click();",Send_Test);

        String textAfter = Send_Test.getText().trim();
```

......
Is there anyone who has experience with get the error messages of Ajaxerror() method using selenium with java?
Thank you for your help

[image: page with send test button]

Comment: It's just a name of a function... look for it to see what it does.  It sounds like it makes a prompt appear in the DOM.  You can test for the appearance of that element. (or the "success" version)

Comment: @pcalkins, The function prompts a message "Message was sent".I want to check if the message was sent or not. But,I can't able to capture the status of the function. Can you help me, How could I do that?

Comment: Seems like you'd need to check from the account the message was sent to.  You might want to manually check it.   If you want to check the response like the site does you'd mock-up the call.

Comment: Thanks, @pcalkins, for your response.
Currently, there are hundreds of mailboxes, and checking all emails manually takes a lot of time. Is there no mechanism for getting the texts from the DOM prompt?

Comment: yes, you'd check the DOM for existence of the prompt... (or alert?  you need to inspect those prompts to see what to target)  Validating the prompt is not necessarily validating that the message has been sent, though.

Comment: I am not sure that validating the DOM doesn't mean that the message has been sent. But, here my target is to check the DOM prompt text content, in order to identify the status of each mailbox.I wonder if there will be a way for it. Thanks once again.